# write json to String instead of file in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

**I am using jackson for converting POJO to JSON**

```
     User user = new User();
    user.setAge(25);
    user.setName("Shahid");

     ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.writeValue("D:/test.json", user);
```

instead of writing it to file , I want to write it to on String variable (`jsonString`) . So that I get the result as follow.

String jsonString= "{"name" : "Shahid","age" : 25}";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(user).
```

Please refer [documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mapper.writeValue(os, user);
String json = os.toString();
```